# How to use str_replace to get rid of the linkattribute id

Tags: php

This is PHP code.
I have a string $heads. This string returns a list item with a link in it with link attributes:

```
<li><a href="#link-to-h2-heading" id="some-id">Example title</a></li>
```

Now I want to get rid of the id in this string so I started using str_replace to get rid of the id="some-id", but I didn't managed to get it working. The id="" is dynamic so it can be any word or combination.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to learn regular expressions. https://php.net/preg_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to do that, as Mitya proposed:

The regular expression (not totally correct): `\s*id="[^"]+"`

Explanation:

- `\s` means search for a whitespace character.
- `\s*` means this whitespace can be missing or multiple. So two white spaces or more would be matched.
- `[]` is used to match a list of characters that you have to specify in between. But if you start with a `^` then it's all characters except the given list. So `[^"]` means any character which isn't the `"` char. The `+` operator is a bit like the `*` operator. It means "multiple times but at least one time". So here I'm matching the *id* value.

Here's the solution that you can test: https://regex101.com/r/WlypLb/1

I've activated the `i` regex option, to make it case insensitive.
The `m` option is for multiple lines, meaning that the search is done on each line of the input when you're using some regex operators like `^` (begin with) or `$` (end with). It's quite usefull if you want to test your input with a list of values. But here, for your case, it doesn't have any effect.

You can generate the PHP code directly from Regex101:

```php
$regex = '/\s*id="[^"]+"/i';
$str = '<li><a href="#link-to-h2-heading" id="some-id">Example title</a></li>';
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($regex, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

But now, if your HTML contains `<li id="some-id-a"><a href="..." id="some-id-b">...</a></li>` then both ids will be removed. In this case you'll have to make a better regular expression that catches the `<a>` tag only. You could do that by first matching the anchor with one regex and then remove the id inside it with a second regex.

Also notice that the id value could be also written like this:

- `<a href="..." id=some-id>...</a>`
- `<a href='...' id='some-id'>...</a>`
- `<a href = "..." id = "some-id">...</a>` because spaces are allowed around the `=` sign. Yes, it's stupid... but it could happen.

You can change the regex if needed but I hope your HTML will always use doublequotes for the attribute values, like it normally should be.

We should also be carefull because you may have an attribute name finishing with *id*. A realistic example where some data attributes could have been injected, for example for the administration of the website, with some JavaScript reading these attributes:

```html
<li id="menu-contact">
  <a href="/contact" id="menu-link-contact" data-edit-id="link34234">Contact</a>
</li>
```

If you use our simple regex as is, we'll unfortunately break the HTML. You can see it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/WlypLb/2

To solve that, we know that **the `id` attribute should be a full word**. We can use the `\b` regex operator to match a "word beginning" or "word ending", leading to `\bid=` instead of `id=`. Or we could assume **the space before should always be there, so `\s*` should be replaced by `\s+`, leading to this more correct regex**: `\s+id="[^"]+"`

So as you see, with the spaces allowed around the equal sign of the attribute and with the possible single quote or none of them, the regular expression starts to get rather complicated: `\s+id\s*=\s*(["']|\b)[\w\d\-_]+\1`
You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/WlypLb/3

In this case of situation, most people recommand using an XML parser such the ones that PHP offer: https://www.php.net/manual/refs.xml.php

But, clearly, for your simple case, a regular expression like `\s+id="[^"]+"` will do the trick and will run much faster than an XML parser. It's just good to know that when the input HTML could probably change because of an update or anything else then the bullet proof regex or the XML parser is best.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Appreciate it very much!

Comment: You're welcome @morrits ! I've edited the answer as I noticed an error. The regex was potentially matching some other attributes that could finish with `id`. Also added some explanation about the fact that single quotes or spaces on attributes can also exist :-/

Comment: Thanks! You are awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

can you try `preg_replace` with some `regex`:

```
$string = preg_replace('#id="[^"]*"#', '', $string);
```

find all phrases of the form `id="` then come with no or more any non `"` then to `"` and replace it with `''(empty)`

Answer (score 1):

this is a solution for what you require using regex :

```
$string = 'li><a href="#link-to-h2-heading" id="some-id">Hello there</a></li>"';
$reg = '/id="[^"]+"/i';
$newString = preg_replace($reg, '', $string);
```